# Laravel exception throwing

Tags: laravel, exception

How to throw an exception in Laravel 5.1. I want to simply throw a custom exception with 400 response code. I don't want to do try and catch. I simply want to throw the exception. Should I first create a class based on the Exception class and then throw it? How do I add a custom message and a response code?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `.php` class in your `app/Exceptions` folder, that would look like something like this:

```
class CustomException extends \Exception
{
    public function report(CustomException $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }
}
```

And then, you can use it like this:

```
throw new CustomException('Your custom message!', 400);
```

You can read more on official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#the-exception-handler).

Comment: this is so complicated